# Joomla - Why does JControllerForm->cancel attempt to check in item?

Tags: joomla, controller

I've come across a situation where, if a user tries to edit a checked out item, it seems they get stuck on the edit page because when they click cancel the controller cancel method attempts to check in the item which obviously it can't do and as a result redirects back to the item view which essentially renders the cancel method button useless...

I can't make sense of this as it would seem to me it would redirect to the list view if it can't check it in...??? Can anyone explain the logic to this because I don't understand.

I don't want to override the method to workaround this without understanding why Joomla does it...

Here is the cancel method from JcontrollerForm:

```
public function cancel($key = null)
{
    JSession::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $table = $model->getTable();
    $checkin = property_exists($table, 'checked_out');
    $context = "$this->option.edit.$this->context";

    if (empty($key))
    {
        $key = $table->getKeyName();
    }

    $recordId = $app->input->getInt($key);

    // Attempt to check-in the current record.
    if ($recordId)
    {
        if ($checkin)
        {
            if ($model->checkin($recordId) === false)
            {
                // Check-in failed, go back to the record and display a notice.
                $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_CHECKIN_FAILED', $model->getError()));
                $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');

                $this->setRedirect(
                    JRoute::_(
                        'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                        . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $key), false
                    )
                );

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean the session data and redirect.
    $this->releaseEditId($context, $recordId);
    $app->setUserState($context . '.data', null);

    $this->setRedirect(
        JRoute::_(
            'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_list
            . $this->getRedirectToListAppend(), false
        )
    );

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit a checked out item if use "save to new."   You are right that if an item is currently checked out it shouldn't attempt to check in prior to the save to new being done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's actually trying to check it in when I want to cancel out of it. Save to new works ok but the user needs to be able to cancel the edit without saving any changes and redirect back to the list view.

Comment: Yes if it's doing that it's a bug. Normally you check in on cancel but in this case given that it was checked out by someone else, it should be more like a close.  Do you see this in debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug actually because if you look at the code in the cancel method (added to my question above), it seems to be behaving as it should. What I don't understand is why it was designed this way because it makes no sense to me.

Comment: You can't allow two people to edit the same article at the same time. You will get a race condition and someone's work will be lost.  So when an article is opened for editing it is checked out.  When it is closed for editing, it is checked back in because now it is safe for someone else to edit.  The whole issue with being checked out most of the time means someone failed to close/cancel properly, that is why you need to train your users always to use cancel or save and close to check the article back in.

Comment: It's definitely a bug because if you open an checked out article but you are not the person it is checked out to, cancelling should not attempt to checkin.

Comment: Wow ok that seems like a significant bug then because as you can see from the `JControllerForm` cancel method, it is clearly trying to check it in... Do you think I should override the cancel method for my component? And should I report the bug?

Comment: Yes you should report the bug. Is this in your component? Are you checking if the user is also the one who checked it out?

Comment: Yes it's in my component. I deliberately set it up so that one user checked out the record and another user viewed and then tried to cancel out of the view.